# simple software licensing in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a JavaScript-Application based on electron which should be saled in the future. I am currently brainstorming some ideas to the licensing-details.

I **dont want to use an required online-activation** as it feels unfair to my customers. When they buy my product, they should own it and be able to use it in 20 years without any activation-servers (it´s more a principle because i dont think anyone uses it in 20 years).

My idea was to create the classic "software-serial-number" which is send to the user after ordering my product. People may bypass this by extracting my electron-app and modify the code and that´s okay, i know i cant do anything (effective) against this.

But i want a protection against the simple "I´ve got a new program! Here, you have it!" because i think entering license information should inform people that the software is not free and entering someones name and his serial might be a barrier - at least for the conscience. It´s a tool for around 15$ and i am hoping that the upcoming license-dialog will let the honest user buy the product.

Any ideas how to do this? I thought at GPG and generation a keypair and give the private-key to the user, but i dont know how to handle this in the code. Any other ideas?